# ipywidgets - widgets.FileUpload, updated CSV file read the CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using jupyterhub and hosting the `.ipynb` file and hosted on server. I have usecase to upload a CSV from localdrive file and read the same for other dataframe tasks.

```
uploader = widgets.FileUpload(
    accept='*.csv',  # Accepted file extension e.g. '.txt', '.pdf', 'image/*', 'image/*,.pdf'
    multiple=False  # True to accept multiple files upload else False
)

display(uploader)


[input_file] = uploader.value
print(input_file)
pd.read_csv(input_file)
```

`print(input_file)` - is printing `Test.csv` which is CSV file name
I am able to print `[input_file]`  but `pd.read_csv(input_file)' is throwing below error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.csv'
```

Not sure were the CSV is uploaded, how can i read that data. Please help.

Comment: Can you add to the question and copy and paste in what is presented when you `print(input_file)`

Comment: @ac24 I have updated the question of print result, which is correctly printing the CSV filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your exact ipywidgets version, but can you try this:

```
input_file = list(uploader.value.values())[0]
content = input_file['content']
content = io.StringIO(content.decode('utf-8'))
df = pd.read_csv(content)
```

Comment: Thank you heaps for your help, I was able to fix this

Comment: No problem. By the way, using `[input_file]=...` is probably fine with a single valued list on the right hand side, but you were using it on a single dictionary, which would be pretty unexpected for anyone else maintaining the code:

Compare `[result] = ['a']`  with `[result] = {'a': 1}`, both end up with `result = 'a'` but the first one is much more expected than the second.